# Insert into MySql database from Javascript window?

Tags: javascript, php

Merry Christmas all.

I have a calender (main page) that, when a user clicks a date a window (booking window) opens within the calender using javascript showing another php page which has a booking form (booking page).  I have a javascript validation set on the main page and everything is working great.

I don't know if it's too much sherry or just my mind away for Christmas but I can't get my head the following.

When the user clicks the submit the entire page refreshes as it should do on a server side but I'm not sure what I'd need to do so that only that window will refresh instead of the entire page.

Is there another way other than using Javascript to enter the data to MySql?  I'm a tad lost.

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT JAVASCRIPT CODE:-

```
var date = (thisId.id);
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "Scripts/NewBooking.php";
var vars = "date="+date+"&jobtime="+jobtime;
var jobtime = "Morning";
hr.open("POST", url, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = return_data;
    }
}
hr.send(vars)
document.getElementById("events").innerHTML = "processing...";
```

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too! What you need is some form of AJAX/asynchronous submission. Does the 'booking window' load in an iframe or a kind of modal/lightbox?

Comment: @Makville - Thank You! :) I'll add the code for that.

Comment: I noticed the jobtime is below the link.  Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you need to use AJAX to do that..
AJAX let you :

1. Update a web page without reloading the page
2. Request data from a server - after the page has loaded
3. Receive data from a server - after the page has loaded
4. Send data to a server - in the background

your code will be something like this:

```
$('#button').on('click',function(){
    $.ajax({
        url :'<?php echo site_url("your link goes here"); ?>',
        type: "POST",
        data : {
            your_data : some_data
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(xhr.responseText);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah I thought so.  Mind plays tricks when it thinks there is some kind of quick cheat get round.

So long way round for me to create a Javascript, call another page with the INSERT info.

Thanks :)

Comment: welcome, i think once you try AJAX you'll never leave it.
it's so amazing and will make your site much better.